# Why does Integer.MAX_VALUE*2 returns -2?

Tags: java, integer

I was looking for a value of `i` where `i==i+1` should always be `true`. Some others used `double` and `float` to find a solution to the problem.

I was trying to answer to a question on stack overflow. And thought about integers, trying to see if that could be possible too.

But while manipulating `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` many times, I found this strange behavior:

`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`

But `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 == -2` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 4 == -4`

This happens only if I use even values like (2,4,6,8,10,12...). When I use odd values except **1**, this happens:

`Integer.MAX_VALUE * n == Integer.MAX_VALUE - n + 1` where `n != Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `n > Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Why is this behaving so? Is there something I am missing?

**EDIT**: I saw someone flagging the question as duplicate but navigating to the referred link, my question is different.

> If it overflows, it goes back to the minimum value and continues from >there. If it underflows, it goes back to the maximum value and continues >from there.

I've carefully read answers from there but none of them explained why:

`Integer.MAX_VALUE*x` should be `-x` if **x** is an even number and `Integer.MAX_VALUE*y` should be `Integer.MAX_VALUE-y+1` if **y** is an odd number.

That's exactly what is confusing me the most.

Comment: which part exactly is not clear to you?

Comment: where `Integer.MAX_VALUE*2==-2` but `Integer.MAX_VALUE*3==2147483645` at least it should be -3 too?

Comment: point understood... interesting question, never though about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Java's signed integers follow [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

In a two's complement representation, negative numbers are represented as an *N*-bit *complement* of their corresponding positive value, i.e. their sum modulo 2<sup>n</sup> is 0.

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647` (hex `0x7FFFFFFF`).
When multiplied, it overflows, and what remains is the lowest 32 bits (i.e. modulo 2<sup>32</sup>):

```
0x7FFFFFFF * 2 = 0x0FFFFFFFE (mod32 = 0xFFFFFFFE = -2)
0x7FFFFFFF * 3 = 0x17FFFFFFD (mod32 = 0x7FFFFFFD = 2147483645)
0x7FFFFFFF * 4 = 0x1FFFFFFFC (mod32 = 0xFFFFFFFC = -4)
0x7FFFFFFF * 5 = 0x27FFFFFFB (mod32 = 0x7FFFFFFB = 2147483643)
0x7FFFFFFF * 6 = 0x2FFFFFFFA (mod32 = 0xFFFFFFFA = -6)
0x7FFFFFFF * 7 = 0x37FFFFFF9 (mod32 = 0x7FFFFFF9 = 2147483641)
```

An interesting property of two's complement representation is that the highest bit corresponds to the *sign* of the value.

Notice how the leftmost 7 results in alternating 0/1 bit 31. That bit happens to control the sign of the result, hence the alternating sign.

Why `0x7FFFFFFF * 2` is `-2` is because `0x7FFFFFFF` in a 31-bit representation (the largest possible representation without overflowing) is `-1`. And -1 * 2 = -2.

You can achieve a similar result if you take `Long.MAX_VALUE` and cast the result to `int`:

```
long x = Long.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
    System.out.println((int)(x * i));
}
```

Just prints:

```
-2
-3
-4
-5
-6
-7
```

Now bit 31 isn't alternating anymore so we get stable results.

Answer (score 1):

2147483647 is the max value, now try executing below set of instructions:

```
int i = 2147483647;
i++;
System.out.println(i);//prints -2147483647 as the 32 bit limit exceeds
```

binary equivalent of 2147483647 is 01111111111111111111111111111111
binary equivalent of 2 is          00000000000000000000000000000010

binary addition is 110000000000000000000000000000000

**NOTE: The last bit at left stands for sign, `int` being 32 bit signed integer**

thus, the number becomes -2147483647

```
i++;
System.out.println(i); // prints -2147483647
```

on the same lines, `2147483647 * 2` is actually -> `2147483647 + 2147483647`

```
int j = 2147483647;
j += 2147483647;
System.out.println(j); // prints -2
```

and thus you answer. 
now when you do `2147483647 * 3`,

it is:

`2147483647 + 2147483647 + 2147483647` = `-2 + 2147483647` = `2147483645`